# MPI creating structs over functions in C?

Tags: c, function, struct, mpi

I'm creating a struct to send over MPI but am having a little trouble with using the struct in other functions..

```
typedef struct Coordinates
{
    int x;
    int y;
} XY;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    .
    .
    .
    const int num_items = 2;
    int blocklengths[2] = {1, 1};
    MPI_Aint offsets [2];
    offsets[0] = offsetof(XY, x);
    offsets[1] = offsetof(XY, y);
    MPI_Datatype types[2] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT};
    MPI_Datatype mpi_new_type;

    MPI_Type_struct(...., &mpi_new_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_new_type);

    // Call some function here depending on rank
    if (rank == 0)
        controlFunction(..);
    else
        someFunction(..);

    return 0;
}

int controlFunction(..)
{
    MPI_Recv(.., mpi_new_type,...);
    .
    .
}

int someFunction(..)
{
    MPI_Send(.., mpi_new_type,...);
    .
    .
}
```

So the basic idea is I create a struct with some data in it and create a new MPI_Datatype to handle the struct over MPI. The issue lies in `controlFunction` and `someFunction` where upon compiling my program using `mpicc file.c -o file` I get the error: `mpi_new_type undeclared` in both the functions.

Is there any way I can access this datatype in other functions?

Thanks.

EDIT - Added more code to show declarations of mpi_new_type as requested.

Comment: Could you show us the declaration of mpi_new_type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `mpi_new_type` is visible only in the scope of the body of the `main` function. The name is undeclared within the scopes of `someFunction`'s and `controlFunction`'s bodies. You can pass the variable as an argument to those

```
 int main() {   
 ...
 if (...)
    controlFunction(mpi_new_type, ...);
 else
    ...
 ...
 }

 int controlFunction(MPI_Dataype mpi_new_type, ...) {
```

or make it a global variable (although don't forget all the reasons why globals are discouraged.)